# What grammatical construction is the idiom "to look the part"

Tags: grammar, verbs

Normally, "look“ is used with prepositions like "at, towards". However, there is this neat construction "to look a part / one's age etc.".

Is this just a shortened version of a comparison with like?

E.g.

> Se looked (like someone at) his age
>
> She looked (like an actor playing) the part

Or is it a grammatical construction where look can take a direct object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I'm coming to the conclusion **I don't look my age**, and I don't act my age. ([source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/look%20one's%20age))
> 2. In his cowboy hat and boots, **he certainly looked the part**. ([source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look%20the%20part))

In both of these, *look* is a **complex-intransitive**<sup>1</sup> verb, with *my age* and *the part* functioning as predicative complements (PCs), not as objects (Os).

The criterion we can apply to both is exchanging the noun phrases (NPs) with adjective phrases (AdjPs) (*I'm coming to the conclusion I don't look **good***<sub>AdjP</sub>; *he certainly looked **handsome***<sub>AdjP</sub>) or bare role NPs, as they are both admissible as PCs, but not as Os.

Another criterion, which isn't sufficient, but is necessary, is that a PC can't be the subject of the corresponding passive clause (<sup><sub>UNGRAMMATICAL</sub></sup>*my age is looked by me*; <sup><sub>UNGRAMMATICAL</sub></sup>*the part was looked by him*), which an O could be.

I'd regard both expressions as idiomatic in meaning, but I don't see why the above analysis wouldn't apply anyway.

---

<sup>1</sup> a term used in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (2002) by Huddleston et al., whose analysis I've tried to follow in this answer